# Can Facebook HipHop (PHP to C++) be compiled and run on Windows

Tags: php, c++, performance, facebook, hiphop

Has someone tried to achieve that?

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the link you've given:

> HipHop for PHP isn't technically a compiler itself. Rather it is a source code transformer. HipHop programmatically transforms your PHP source code into highly optimized C++ and then uses **g++** to compile it.

You'll have to replace the g++ compiler for one that runs on windows like [mingw](http://www.mingw.org).